# how to componentize purescript-halogen application

Tags: purescript, halogen

I would like to write specific components of my frontend using Purescript's Halogen.

For example, I would like to create a registration form using Halogen.  It would look something like below:

```
module RegistrationForm where

import Prelude

...

-- | The state of the application
newtype State = State { email :: String, password :: String }

derive instance genericState :: Generic State
instance showState :: Show State where show = gShow
instance eqState :: Eq State where eq = gEq

initialState :: State
initialState = State { email: "", password: "" }

-- | Inputs to the state machine
data Input a = FormSubmit a
             | UpdateEmail String a
             | UpdatePassword String a
             | NoAction a

type AppEffects eff = HalogenEffects (ajax :: AJAX, console :: CONSOLE | eff)

ui :: forall eff . Component State Input (Aff (AppEffects eff))
ui = component render eval
  where
    render :: Render State Input
    render (State state) = H.div_
        [ H.h1_ [ H.text "Register" ]
        , ...
        ]

    eval :: Eval Input State Input (Aff (AppEffects eff))
    eval (NoAction next) = pure next
    eval (FormSubmit next) = do
        ...
    eval (UpdateEmail email next) = do
        ...
    eval (UpdatePassword password next) = do
        ...

runRegistrationForm :: Eff (AppEffects ()) Unit
runRegistrationForm = runAff throwException (const (pure unit)) $ do
    { node: node, driver: driver } <- runUI ui initialState
    appendTo ".registration" node
```

Similarly, I have a `LoginForm` module that handles logging a user into the application.

I'm wondering **how to go about organizing my source code, building my source code, and calling my Purescript code from Javascript**?

Currently, my source code is organized like the following:

```
$ cd my-application/
$ tree
.
├── bower.json
├── README.md
├── site/
│   └── index.html
├── src/
│   ├── LoginForm.purs
│   └── RegistrationForm.purs
└── test/
    └── Test.purs
```

However, since I don't have a `Main.purs`, I can't do any of the following to build my source code:

```
$ pulp build --to site/app.js
$ pulp browserify --to site/app.js
$ pulp server
```

It would be nice to be able to build my purescript code into logical javascript files.  For instance, `src/LoginForm.purs` could be built as `site/loginForm.js`, and `src/RegistrationForm.purs` could be built as `site/registrationForm.js`.

Then, I could include `loginForm.js` and `registrationForm.js` in my actual html pages as need-be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pulp doesn't really cover this use case, it's only intended for apps where there is a single `Main`.

I'd suggest using a `gulp` setup to achieve this, using a gulpfile something like this:

```
"use strict";

var gulp = require("gulp"),
    purescript = require("gulp-purescript"),
    webpack = require("webpack-stream");

var sources = [
  "src/**/*.purs",
  "bower_components/purescript-*/src/**/*.purs",
];

var foreigns = [
  "src/**/*.js",
  "bower_components/purescript-*/src/**/*.js"
];

gulp.task("make", function() {
  return purescript.psc({
    src: sources,
    ffi: foreigns
  });
});

var mkBundleTask = function (name, main) {

  gulp.task("prebundle-" + name, ["make"], function() {
    return purescript.pscBundle({
      src: "output/**/*.js",
      output: "tmp/js/" + name + ".js",
      module: main,
      main: main
    });
  });

  gulp.task("bundle-" + name, ["prebundle-" + name], function () {
    return gulp.src("tmp/js/" + name + ".js")
      .pipe(webpack({
        resolve: { modulesDirectories: ["node_modules"] },
        output: { filename: name + ".js" }
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest("site/js"));
  });

  return "bundle-" + name;
};

gulp.task("bundle", [
  mkBundleTask("loginForm", "LoginForm"),
  mkBundleTask("registrationForm", "RegistrationForm")
]);

gulp.task("default", ["bundle"]);
```

That might not be quite right, but I extracted it from how we do things with SlamData so it's definitely along the right lines.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with `pulp`, using the `--to` and `--main` options:

```
pulp build --main LoginForm -O --to site/loginForm.js
pulp build --main RegistrationForm -O --to site/registrationForm.js
```

Of course, the `LoginForm` and `RegistrationForm` modules will both need to export a value called `main` for this to work.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that requires you to run `pulp` twice.  I'll need to have an additional `gulpfile` or `Makefile` to specify all the different invocations of `pulp`.  I might as well just use `gulp`.

Comment: The normal approach here is to put it inside "scripts" in package.json. This solution does have the clear advantage of being two lines rather than ~40.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the Javascript ecosystem.  Could you edit your answer and add a sample `package.json` showing what it would look like?  Or even just add a link to a page describing it?

Comment: Sure, here's Prelude: https://github.com/purescript/purescript-prelude/blob/master/package.json

Comment: All of the purescript core libraries use pulp, and most of the non-core ones do too, so there are plenty of examples to be found on GitHub.

Comment: So, if I add the two lines from your answer to `scripts.build` in `package.json`, will they automatically get run when I do a `pulp build`?

Comment: No; pulp doesn't read package.json. In this case, your build command would become `npm run build`.

Comment: So I guess I still have to use an external build tool--npm?  Pulp can't do it alone?

Comment: Also, if I go the `npm` route, what would happen if I run `pulp server`?  Would it serve both my loginform.js and registrationform.js?

Comment: Pulp can't do it alone, no (but npm isn't a build tool). I don't use pulp server so I don't know about that.